# Check if function returns any data in Ajax and WebMethod

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I've developed the following system that returns endless scroll data on an aspx page. It works perfectly well. However I have a small problem checking whether the database has reached the end row and no data is returned.

With the following code the javascript function keeps on calling the webmethod everytime the page scroll hits the bottom although there is no data to return. How can I check there is no data to avoid those meaningless function calls?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var offset = 0;
    var fetch = 30;

function Load() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "UserControls/uc_functions.aspx/LoadLatest",
            data: "{offset :" + offset + ", fetch: " + fetch + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != "") { $('.latest').append(data.d); } 
                else {alert("no data"); completed = true; } //I never get this alert even when there is no data returned from the database
            }
        })
    };

$(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 10) {
            Load(offset, fetch);
            offset = offset + fetch;
        }
    });
});


[WebMethod]
public static string LoadLatest(int offset, int fetch)
    {  
        var LoadSql = db.Query("Exec dbo.SD_unionServices @0, @1", offset, fetch);");
        foreach (var item in LoadSql)
        { 
           Load_sb.Append(item.title + "<br />"); 
        }

        if(LoadSql.Count() > 0)
        return Load_sb.ToString();
        else
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

UPDATE
To check whether the data is empty or not I used data.d instead of data

```
 if (data.d != "") { $('.latest').append(data.d); }
```

Instead of

```
 if (data != "") { $('.latest').append(data.d); }
```

Comment: Is `data` ever truly empty? Is it possible that `LoadSql` is returning a singular empty item causing your method to return a line break or a non-zero length empty string?

Comment: Well I'm 99% sure that the data is empty since nothing is added to the page through $('.latest').append(data.d);

Answer (score 2):

Improve this to return string.Empty when there is no data available.

```
public static string LoadLatest(int offset, int fetch)
{  
    var LoadSql = db.Query("Exec dbo.SD_unionServices @0, @1", offset, fetch);");
    foreach (var item in LoadSql)
    { 
       Load_sb.Append(item.title + "<br />"); 
    }

    if(Load_sb.Count() > 0)
       return Load_sb.ToString();
    else
       return string.Empty;

}
```

Comment: Very nice answer, I have created my own, where I refer to your idea, but with some further tweaking.

Comment: I followed your advice and improved the script by adding if(LoadSql.Count() > 0) return Load_sb.ToString();  else return string.Empty;

Comment: Have you checked that the else block value was returned and you still don't get empty data?

Answer (score 2):

**Oluwafemi** is right, when he points out that

> Improve this to return string.Empty when there is no data available.

I would also add that it is highly important to not post for data if you have reached the end of the list. It is for the benefit to people having slow internet connection:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var offset = 0;
    var fetch = 30;
    var completed = false;

function Load() {
        if (!completed) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "UserControls/uc_functions.aspx/LoadLatest",
                data: "{offset :" + offset + ", fetch: " + fetch + "}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != "") { $('.latest').append(data.d); } 
                    else {alert("no data"); completed = true;} //I never get this alert even when there is no data returned from the database
                }
            });
        }
    };

$(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 10) {
            Load(offset, fetch);
            offset = offset + fetch;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: My name is Oluwafemi :)

Comment: I improved the script based on Oluwafemi advice but I still don't get an empty string..... I agree not to post for data when the end of list is reached. That's exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks for all the advice.

Comment: @Oluwafemi, sorry for that, I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Gloria, how do you use Load_sb? Can you debug your function and see what is its value when you are trying to get elements from an offset outside your bounds?

Comment: I solved the problem by checking data.d instead of data as follows: if (data.d != "") { $('.latest').append(data.d); } and it works well

Answer (score 0):

the `trim` function removes all the spaces in the data. Provided it cant trim data , it is pretty obvious that there would be no data present

```
if (!$.trim(data)){   
    //no data
}
else{   
    //data found!
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer, and explain why this solves the problem.